# Admob banner is not showing up

Tags: android, admob, banner

My admob banner is not showing up, I have gone through the guide found here
https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start

MainActivity

```
private AdView mAdView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");
    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In my Manifest, I have this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Project Gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}



apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Log

```
01-31 20:44:49.586 3556-3556/? D/ucsBai_ConnectionManager: mPackageReceiver Action android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED
01-31 20:44:58.836 19607-19607/com.example.myapplication I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 10084
01-31 20:44:58.836 19607-19607/com.example.myapplication I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
01-31 20:44:58.836 19607-19607/com.example.myapplication D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
01-31 20:44:58.836 19607-19607/com.example.myapplication D/FA: AppMeasurement singleton hash: 23949389
01-31 20:44:58.846 19607-19607/com.example.myapplication V/FA: Collection enabled
01-31 20:44:58.846 19607-19607/com.example.myapplication V/FA: App package, google app id: com.example.myapplication, 1:665936977222:android:13c3c6a65bcbec53
01-31 20:44:58.846 19607-19607/com.example.myapplication I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
                                                                 adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.example.myapplication
01-31 20:44:58.906 19607-19607/com.example.myapplication V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
01-31 20:44:58.916 19607-20434/com.example.myapplication V/FA: Using measurement service
01-31 20:44:58.916 19607-20434/com.example.myapplication V/FA: Connecting to remote service
01-31 20:44:59.816 19607-20434/com.example.myapplication V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
01-31 20:45:00.116 19607-20434/com.example.myapplication D/FA: Connected to remote service
01-31 20:45:00.116 19607-20434/com.example.myapplication V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 2
01-31 20:45:05.156 19607-20434/com.example.myapplication V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

Comment: Sometimes admob takes time to show banner, it happened to me and started working after sometime.

Answer (score 3):

First Open the https://apps.admob.com/ and then select your application from there now select the Monetize Tab from there now expand the view setup instruction

[image]

Here you have to put your App ID

```
MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-1440645979698474~6985293144"); // replace with yours
```

And for xml [image]

Select from adunits

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-1440645979698474/3892225947">
```

Replace with your adUnitId and you are done.

Answer (score 2):

You put your Ad unit ID instend of App ID.

```
MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), here your app id will come );
```

And this is your ad id both are different just change above code and put app id instead of your Ad unit ID.

This is your Ad unit ID

```
ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111
```

Hope this will works.
Cheers!

Comment: Is this my app id "com.example.myapplication" ?

Comment: Nope not that one it will be start with ca-app-pub ....... just go to setting in AdMob account and app management by clicking on it you will have list of your application at which you can find out the app id. did you get my point?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you have your payment/billing info set up in order to serve your ads. Ensure you test your ad banner first with teh supplied test ID.

Comment: I was searching for this reason since 2-3 days and came to know strange about this issue this is not a programming issue it is actually admob settings if you have not submitted payment account details then ads are not enabled so if you have new account then you must fill payment account details to enable ads, it will take arround 24 hrs to activate. kindly check below link.

https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7652476?hl=en